# Using YAML to define one to many relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping, yaml

I undertake a project where mapping for doctrine was based on YAML.

I need to create one to many  relationship between two entities: Post and Image (a post can have zero or any number of images).

**under Post.orm.yml:**

```
TEST\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Post:
    type: entity
    table: null
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        postUserId:
            type: integer
            column: post_user_id
        postDate:
            type: datetime
            column: post_date
        postContent:
            type: text
            column: post_content
        postTitle:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: post_title
        commentStatus:
            type: boolean
            column: comment_status   
    oneToMany:
       images:
         targetEntity: Image
         mappedBy: pos
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**under Image.orm.yml**:

```
TEST\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Image:
    type: entity
    table: null
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        filePersistencePath:
            type: string
        subDir:
            type: string
    manyToOne:
      pos:
        targetEntity: Post
        inversedBy: images
      joinColumn:
        referencedColumnName: id

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**probelm:**
when I update database schema, I get the following error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
 Notice: Undefined index: targetEntity in C:\xampp\htdocs\bghitn\vendor\doct
 rine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver.php line 399
```

I don't understand this message. Your help is always appreciated.

**Edit:** This is the result of updating schema with --dump-sql

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\bghitn>php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
ALTER TABLE image ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C53D045F4B89032C FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFER
ENCES post (id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_C53D045F4B89032C ON image (post_id)
```

Comment: FYI i have almost the same yml and it works for me. can you try to add 2 spaces before pos and targetEntity to respect the number of spaces of the file? you can also try to fill the "table" field even though i don't think it solves it

Comment: @goto: I tried your advice but it is unfortunately not working. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Instead of mentioning just the entity name in the targetEntity field, provide the full path to the Entity. Also, try to update schema after removing the tables for these entities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the oneToMany relation from the post entity and retain the manyToOne relation in the image entity

```
manyToOne:
  post:
    targetEntity: TEST\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Post
    joinColumn:
      name: post_id
      referencedColumnName: id
```

Be careful about the indentation.

Comment: Thank you @Praveesh. Should I understand that, in relationnal dbs, I only need to specify the one-to-many relationship in one side (parent or child), not the two sides? PS: I still have problems implementing your solution.

Comment: I have now An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE image ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES Post (id)':
=SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails. Do you know what may be the cause? Thank you for your time

Comment: The error could happen if you're trying to generate the both the entities at the same time. Please try generating Post entity first and  then generate the image entity

Comment: I am only updating database schema, entities are already generated.

Comment: Please generate the entities again and then update the schema. To generate entities, run php app/console doctrine:generate:entities 'BUNDLENAME'

Comment: I did but in vain. I got the same exceptions.

Comment: Could you please post the output of php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

Comment: thank you @Praveesh for your time. I posted the result as an edit.

Comment: I resolved the issue Praveesh. I deleted the column post_id from the database via phpmyadmin, then I executed update-schema.